# how to handle a dynamic string?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to put into a string variable a dynamic value, so I have this code

XML strings:

```
<resources>
        <string name="Destination">%1$s!</string>
</resources>
```

XML activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditText
       android:hint="@string/Destination"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

java:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.Destination), addressComplete);
```

But the system says

> variable 'text' is never used

and in the EditText box in the activity there is the string

> %1$s!

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't show you doing anything with the variable `text`, so what the system is saying is correct. Also, it's not entirely clear what you're asking. You want to concatenate some other text with your `Destination` String resource or replace it?

Comment: I want to put the value "addressComplete" (built up in java) into the variable '%1$s!' that is placed in XML string resources:  <string name="Destination">%1$s!</string>;  so I want to replace it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is complete your code.

You need to modify your `XML` layout so that your `EditText` has an ID:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/destinationInput"
       android:hint="@string/Destination"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in your Java, you get a reference to the `EditText`, and change the hint to your `text` variable:

```
String text = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.Destination), addressComplete);
EditText destinationInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.destinationInput);
destinationInput.setHint(text);
```